# Heroku deployment failure-- psycopg2 installation failure

Tags: python, django, heroku, psycopg2, pipenv

I am getting a persisting error when I am deploying my python/Django project to heroku. I keep getting

```
"It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
    
    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>)."
```

and when I install psycopg2 I also get the same message, any help please
github repo Link : https://github.com/moeabraham/finalsoccer

Also, they might be helpful, when typing commands for pip I usually get an error unless I wrote it as pipenv! I am a beginner and this has been confusing so far :)

Comment: Use the `psycopg2-binary` package instead of `psycopg2`

Comment: still the same error, I also tried that yesterday